# Computing slope of changing data

Tags: r, subset, linear-regression

In R, I have a dataset of (x, y) points that is constantly being updated via simulation (values are appended to the end of the dataset).

I would like to compute the slope (via a linear model) of the line created by the data using only the last 10 listed datapoints.

The confusion here arises from the fact that the data are changing, and so I suspect a loop may be needed to iterate over the indices of the datapoints.

In R, one usually does something like

```
linreg <- lm(y ~ x, data = d) # set up linear model
summary.linreg <- summary(linreg) # output summary of model
beta1 <- coef(summary.linreg)[2] # extract slope
```

The change that is needed in my case is in linreg, specifically

```
linreg <- lm(y[?] ~ x[?], data = d) # subset response and predictor
```

For a non-changing dataset of 10 x-y points, one simply does [?] = [1:10] and the problem is solved. In my case though, I am at a standstill as to the best way to proceed efficiently.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You don't need `summary` if you only want the slope. `coef(linreg)` should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, don't subset inside the formula. Subset the data.frame. Inside your loop, after each database update, do this:

```
linreg <- lm(y ~ x, data = tail(d, 10))
```

If you want to loop over a data.frame rows, do this:

```
linreg <- lm(y ~ x, data = d[i:(i+9),])
```

If your data.frame is large and you only need the slope, you should use the more low-level function `lm.fit` for better performance. There might also be packages that provide functions for rolling regression.

Comment: Thanks for the response!